# Charging rent and adding house after

Tags: monopoly-deal

When playing Monopoly Deal, if a player plays a rent card can they then add a house while the player who was charged the rent card organizing the payment for the rent card?

Or should the person have thought of it beforehand instead of adding it after and expecting the other person to pay?

Answer (score 2):

While the player can add a house to a property set after playing a **Rent** card, the house will only be added *after* the  first action has completed, meaning the target player will not need to pay for the house.

The only card that can be played at any time is **Just Say No**, otherwise each action is taken as a whole before moving onto the next one.